# Using EXISTS and GetProfileAttrAsList in a Siebel calculated field

Tags: siebel

In our Siebel 7.8 application, we have three entities: service requests (SR), groups and employees. Each employee can be member of one or many groups, and each service request can be assigned to one or many groups too.

I have a requeriment to create a calculated field on the service request BC, which will indicate if the current user belongs to any of the groups asociated with the service request.

I already have created a multivalue field, called `SR Groups`, on the service request BC. I have also another multivalue field, `Employee Groups`; this one is on the `Personalization Profile` business component, which means that Siebel will generate automatically a multivalued profile attribute with the same name. All of the above is working as expected.

Next I've created this calculated field:

```
IIf(InList([SR Groups], GetProfileAttrAsList("Employee Groups")), "Y", "N")
```

It works, but it only checks if the SR's primary group is one of the current user's groups. I need to check all the SR groups, not only the primary one. So, I have created another calculated field:

```
IIf(EXISTS([SR Groups] = GetProfileAttrAsList("Employee Groups")), "Y", "N")
```

This one doesn't work. It shows always "N". However, according to [this Bookshelf document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/PersAdm/PersAdmUserProf19.html#wp1004507):

> a typical usage of the EXISTS operator in this scenario is `EXISTS ([Targeted States] = GetProfileAttrAsList("State"))`. This does a many-to-many match of the MVG Business Component Field Targeted State against the MVG profile attribute State.

Which is exactly what I'm trying to do, without success. I can't see any difference between my expression and the example one. And there isn't any of the typical Bookshelf warnings, like *"if you're going to use this function, you must activate the Link Specification property of the MVF"*, or anything like that.

The business component is based on a specialized class, CSSBCServiceRequest, but <strike>I don't think that should be a problem in this case</strike> - switching it to CSSBCBase doesn't fix the issue either. The only thing not working seems to be the `EXISTS` operator, which is pretty standard in Siebel.

Also, if I execute a query on the application with the expression `EXISTS([SR Groups] = GetProfileAttrAsList("Employee Groups"))`, it doesn't filter out any service request as it should.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I've been able to figure out a workaround. I'd still like to know why my first attempt didn't work, but anyway...

Given that the problem with my first attempt seemed to be matching a many-to-many relationship between the MVF and the multivalued profile attribute, I've split it in two one-to-many matches:

1. In the link, I've stablished a search specification property. This way, my multivalue field will contain only groups associated with the user:

   ```
   InList([Group], GetProfileAttrAsList("Employee Groups"))
   ```
2. In the BC, it only remains to check if there is any value in the MVF or not:

   ```
   IIf(EXISTS([Filtered SR Groups] IS NOT NULL), "Y", "N")
   ```